# Is there any risk in posting "local info" to the Internet?

Tags: privacy, data-leakage, file-upload

Previously when I posted a screenshot online, someone told me to *erase out* my usernames, computer names, domain names, etc:

[image: hide domain local information]

Is there actually a need to do so?

A [quick Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=sharepoint%20configuration%20installing) shows that many people in fact broadly publicize these info.

How can leaking these harmless miscellaneous info allow an attacker to penetrate or hack my computers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When performing pen-tests, it's amazing how much information can be gathered by finding the StackExchange accounts of employees. Server naming patterns for example can be quite helpful, makes finding targets easier.

Test environments rarely are secured properly - or at least to the same level as production systems. If you can get into a test system, it's disturbingly common to be able to use that to then make it into production systems.

Any information leaked can help an attacker - even minor things can help an attacker gain a better understanding of the target environment.

Comment: from stack exchange user's question can we understand what they know and what is their knowledge level? and with their information in pictures find their location and attack and destroy them?

Comment: You can learn what technologies are in use, you can get a rough idea of how knowledgeable they are, and in some cases you can get insight to how they secure their systems. It's an amazing amount of data if you invest the time to do the research.

Comment: Don't forget to check and scrub the [metadata](http://www.controlledvocabulary.com/socialmedia/) too, especially if you use a [GPS enabled camera/phone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geotagging).

Comment: how about FB and photos and information there? all you mentioned forbidden?

Comment: When I research a company and its employees - I'll look everywhere. I'm not above fake Facebook and LinkedIn accounts to gather data. It's a hard thing to defend against - you have trusting employees that don't see the harm, and people like me, who can find value in even the smallest things.

Answer (score 5):

Because information leakage is still information leakage. If it's not relevant to the question why would you include it in the question? You just do it to get a feeling of security.

Also people are posting configuration questions, which may or may not open up security holes.

Also even a test environment can contain valuable information, including confidential information.